# synchronized method not working as Lock ?? why not make a lock on count

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety, locking, synchronize

As given below code I have a use for the intensive lock (monitor) for my `count` variable and only a single `Thread` can be accessed at a time by making  `synchIncrement()` method to be a synchronized method. Then the O/P should be `20000` but still some time difference value is coming.

Why?

```
public class SynchBlockThread {
    private int count = 0;

    private synchronized void synchIncrement() {
        count++;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SynchBlockThread sBT = new SynchBlockThread();
        sBT.doWork();

    }

    private  void doWork() {
        Thread t1 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                for(int i = 0; i<10000; i++) {
                    synchIncrement();
                }
            }
        });

        Thread t2 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                for(int i = 0; i<10000; i++) {
                    synchIncrement();
                }
            }
        });

        t1.start();
        t2.start();

        try {
            t1.join();
            t1.join();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println(count);
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: It's not necessary to provide a screenshot of the whole screen to prove that you are getting a value different from `20000`. By default, we believe you :)

Answer (score 4):

Quite a hard one to spot.

At the end of the `doWork()` method you join `Thread t1` twice, so `Thread t2` is still doing its work when the result is printed.

To express it in code:

```
try {
    t1.join();
    t1.join();
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

should instead be

```
try {
    t1.join();
    t2.join();
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The synchronised method does its job right. The problem is that you aren't waiting for the second `Thread`. `count` can be printed **before** the second thread terminates, so you should add `t2.join();` as well:

```
try {
    t1.join();
    t2.join();
} catch (InterruptedException e) { ... }
```

Let's consider a more interesting version of your method:

```
private void doWork() throws InterruptedException {
    final int n = 2;

    final CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(n);
    final ExecutorService service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(n);
    final Runnable task = () -> {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
            synchIncrement();
        }
        latch.countDown();
    };

    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        service.execute(task);
    }

    latch.await();
    service.shutdown();
    System.out.println(count);
}
```

I introduced a fixed-size `ExecutorService` to not create threads on my own. I wrote a `CountDownLatch` to know when all the tasks finish execution, so I can shut down the service and print the result.